# Jsoncpp problems

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am using Jsoncpp to parse json-formats for c++. 
I do not understand how it works though; there is a lack of documentation and examples to get me started, and I was wondering if anyone could give me some quick pointers. The only examples I've found deals with files...

1. I'm using a HTTP stack to get a json-message in a buffer. For example, a buffer contains the message `{"state":"Running"}`. How do I use the Json::reader to parse this? Again the only example I've found deals with reading from files
2. How do you write values to a Json-message? For example I want to write `"monkey : no"` and `"running : yes"` to a Json-message which I can then use in my GET request.

Thanks

UPDATE:

on 1), for example, how to parse a buffer containing a json-message like this:

```
char* buff;
uint32_t buff_size;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this is good sample for first part of your question:

```
Json::Value values;
Json::Reader reader;
reader.parse(input, values);

Json::Value s = values.get("state","default value");
```

Comment: yeah that's what I'm looking for; I'm not sure how to use reader.parse() though on a buffer; updated OP

Comment: I think there is no problem to use a buffer instead of a string, but if you have something like `char buffer[max]` you can use `parse (buffer,buffer+max-1, values)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is anything but lack of documentation. Yes, it's mainly reference documentation, but it's quite good and well cross-linked.

1. Just **[read the documentation](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_reader.html#f1da6c976ad1e96c742804c3853eef94)**
2. Just **[use this class](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_fast_writer.html)** or possibly *[use the other class](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_styled_writer.html)*

Comment: I have, and I don't fully understand it, which is why I am making this topic

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: Than you'll have to explain what you don't understand on it. The `Json::Reader::parse` method has 3 overloads. One for input stream (which may be a stringstream), one is for string represented as pointer to beginning and pointer to terminating NUL and one for std::string. The writer classes have simple `write` method that returns a `std::string`, or you can just write the Value to an ostream (including stringstream) using standard operator `<<`. You however have to build the Value, which is also quite well documented. The main page even has a sample...

Comment: I have to agree with KaiserJohaan, this json library's documentation is very lacking.  It seems to work well once you figure things out, but it was difficult to learn how to use it.

Comment: [Docs](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/) are up-to-date now. The [wiki](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/wiki) can be helpful too. The older `Readers` were confusing and are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for your reference, below:

> file.json

```
{
"B":"b_val2",
"A":{
        "AA":"aa_val1", 
        "AAA" : "aaa_val2",
        "AAAA" : "aaaa_val3"
     },
"C":"c_val3",
"D":"d_val4"
}
```

[jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/files.html) usage scenario as below, for above sample json file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "json/json.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;
const Json::Value defValue;         //used for default reference
std::ifstream ifile("file.json");

bool isJsonOK = ( ifile != NULL && reader.parse(ifile, root) );
if(isJsonOK){

    const Json::Value s = root.get("A",defValue);
    if(s.isObject()){

        Json::Value s2 = s.get("AAA","");
        cout << "s2 : " << s2.asString() << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "value for key \"A\" is not object type !" << endl;
    }
}
else
    cout << "json not OK !!" << endl;

return 1;
```

}

**Output::**

> s2 : aaa_val2

Additionally, I have used the ["amalgamate.py"](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp#generating-amalgamated-source-and-header) for generating and using the jsoncpp for the sample source above.